# Max function not returning correct result

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the maximum value from an array using max finction in php. However despite making sure that the array appears as I expect using print_r, the max($array) returns the wrong result. 
Please see the code below, I used "simple_html_dom.php" from  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. I am expecting a value of 220, but when I echo max($items) it returns 24 when submit is clicked. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
<html>

<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="google"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';  

if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q'];
$search = ucwords($search);
$search = str_replace(' ', '_', $search);  
$html = file_get_html("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$search");

?>
<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $search; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php
$items = array();
foreach ($html->find('img') as $element): ?>


<?php $photo = $element->src;
$logo = 'Logo';
if(strpos($photo, $logo)) 
{


if (preg_match_all('/[0-9]+px/', $photo, $result)) {
echo '<br/>';

$rp = trim($result[0][0],"px") .'<br/>';
$items[] = $rp;

} else {
echo "Not found";
}
} 

?>              

<?php endforeach; echo max($items);
print_r($items);?>
</ol>
<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match_all()` and then only storing the first result (`$result[0][0]`)? Wouldn't a simple call to `preg_match()` be more efficient? Also, please indent your code.

Comment: Where is the result of `print_r`?

Comment: before storing $rp to $items convert it to integer. $items[] = (int)$rp;

Comment: `$rp = trim($result[0][0],"px") .'<br/>';` ... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's an integer, simply change `$items[] = $rp;` to `$items[] = intval($rp);`... As an example this will change the array entry from `'220<br/>'` (string) to `220` (integer).

Comment: You should also change `max($items)` to `max($items).'<br/>'` to keep the logic of the code. Also obviously you *should* remove the original `.'<br/>'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is result of var_dump($items):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '220<br/>' (length=8)
  1 => string '24<br/>' (length=7)
```

As you see, it takes it as a string. So `max()` works as it should, and you need to properly format it first, cut tags and cast to `int`.